# How do I run two pre-built jQuery animation sequences in parallel with a single callback when both are finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have some reusable animation sequence functions made with jQuery animate. I would like to run two of these in parallel, triggered from the same point, with a single callback when both are completed. Any suggestions on how I do this?

A simple example with two animation sequences that I want to run in parallet would be as follows:

```js
function deleteel(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

function animation1(inputcallback){
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.style.position = "absolute";
    div1.style.left = "0px";
    div1.style.top = "0px";
    div1.style.width = "10px";
    div1.style.height = "10px";
    div1.style.backgroundColor="red";
    document.getElementById("animationcontainer").appendChild(div1);

    $(div1).animate({top: "50"}, "slow", function() {
        $(div1).animate({left: "+50"}, "slow", function() {
            $(div1).animate({top: "20", left: "0"}, "slow", function() {
                $(div1).animate({height: "50", top: "110", left: "0"}, "slow", function() {
                    $(div1).remove();
                    inputcallback();
                });        
            });
        });
    });
    
}

function animation2(inputcallback){
    var div1 = document.createElement("div");
    div1.style.position = "absolute";
    div1.style.left = "100px";
    div1.style.top = "100px";
    div1.style.width = "15px";
    div1.style.height = "15px";
    div1.style.backgroundColor="blue";
    document.getElementById("animationcontainer").appendChild(div1);

    $(div1).animate({top: "10"}, "fast", function() {
        $(div1).animate({left: "+60"}, "slow", function() {
            $(div1).animate({top: "200", left: "100"}, "slow", function() {
                $(div1).animate({width: "50", top: "10", left: "100"}, "slow", function() {
                    $(div1).remove();
                    inputcallback();
                });        
            });
        });
    });
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="animationcontainer" style="position:relative; width:500px; height:500px; background-color:grey"></div>
<button onclick="animation1(function () { alert('Finished');})">Animation 1</button>
<button onclick="animation2(function () { alert('Finished');})">Animation 2</button>
<button onclick="">Both animations</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by returning promises from the functions instead of using callbacks

```
function animation1(){
    var div1 = $("<div />", {
        css : {
            position   : 'absolute',
            left       : '0px',
            top        : '0px',
            width      : '10px',
            height     : '10px',
            background : 'red'
        }
    });

    $("#animationcontainer").append(div1);

    return div1.animate({top    : "50" }, "slow")
               .animate({left   : "+50"}, "slow")
               .animate({top    : "20", left : "0" }, "slow")
               .animate({height : "50", top  : "110", left: "0"}, "slow")
               .promise()
               .done(function() {
                   $(this).remove();
               });
}
```

Then add proper event handlers

```
$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    animation1().done(function() {
        alert('finished');
    });
});
```

and for the last one, to handle both animations, you do

```
$('#button3').on('click', function() {
    $.when(animation1(), animation2()).done(function() {
        alert('finished');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmx46syv/1/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery´s deferreds

```
$.when(
    $element1.animate(...).promise(),
    $element2.animate(...).promise()
).done(function() {
    alert("Both animations are finished");
});
```

```js
var $el1 = $('#el1'),
    $el2 = $('#el2');

$.when(
    $el1.animate({'left': 100}).promise(),
    $el2.animate({'left': 200}, 2000).promise()
).done(function() {
    alert("Both animations are finished");
});
```

```css
#el1, #el2 { position: absolute; top: 0; left:0; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red }
#el2 { background: blue; top: 100px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="el1"></div>
<div id="el2"></div>
```

- [here](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/) you will find an example that explains deferreds

Answer (score 1):

If I am able to understand you want to run same callback after completion of animations but only once. Following code will do it. This is little bit old school but works.

We need to somehow identify that we have ran callback. So we pass a token to callback. It then identifies if token is present (means not run for that token) and it removes token and run code.

```
var tokens = [];

function animCallback(token) {

  var i = tokens.indexOf(token);

  if (i < 0) {
    //token already removed
    return;
  }

  tokens.splice(i, 1);

  alert('finished');
}

function animateBoth() {
  tokens.push('mytoken');
  animation1(function() {
    animCallback('mytoken');
  });
  animation2(function() {
    animCallback('mytoken');
  });
}
```

```js
function deleteel(element) {
  element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}

var tokens = [];

function animCallback(token) {

  var i = tokens.indexOf(token);

  if (i < 0) {
    //token already removed
    return;
  }

  tokens.splice(i, 1);

  alert('finished');
}

function animateBoth() {
  tokens.push('mytoken');
  animation1(function() {
    animCallback('mytoken');
  });
  animation2(function() {
    animCallback('mytoken');
  });
}

function animation1(inputcallback) {
  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.style.position = "absolute";
  div1.style.left = "0px";
  div1.style.top = "0px";
  div1.style.width = "10px";
  div1.style.height = "10px";
  div1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  document.getElementById("animationcontainer").appendChild(div1);

  $(div1).animate({
    top: "50"
  }, "slow", function() {
    $(div1).animate({
      left: "+50"
    }, "slow", function() {
      $(div1).animate({
        top: "20",
        left: "0"
      }, "slow", function() {
        $(div1).animate({
          height: "50",
          top: "110",
          left: "0"
        }, "slow", function() {
          $(div1).remove();
          inputcallback();
        });
      });
    });
  });

}

function animation2(inputcallback) {
  var div1 = document.createElement("div");
  div1.style.position = "absolute";
  div1.style.left = "100px";
  div1.style.top = "100px";
  div1.style.width = "15px";
  div1.style.height = "15px";
  div1.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  document.getElementById("animationcontainer").appendChild(div1);

  $(div1).animate({
    top: "10"
  }, "fast", function() {
    $(div1).animate({
      left: "+60"
    }, "slow", function() {
      $(div1).animate({
        top: "200",
        left: "100"
      }, "slow", function() {
        $(div1).animate({
          width: "50",
          top: "10",
          left: "100"
        }, "slow", function() {
          $(div1).remove();
          inputcallback();
        });
      });
    });
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="animateBoth()">Both animations</button>
<div id="animationcontainer" style="position:relative; width:500px; height:500px; background-color:grey"></div>
<button onclick="animation1(function () { alert('Finished');})">Animation 1</button>
<button onclick="animation2(function () { alert('Finished');})">Animation 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do it in pure js way if you want, not as elegant as the promises and defers, but fyi.

```js
var calledOnce = false;

function doBoth() {
  setTimeout(doAnimation1, 1);
  setTimeout(doAnimation2, 1);
}
function doAnimation1() {
   animation1(cb);
}
function doAnimation2() {
   animation2(cb);
}

function cb() {
  if (!calledOnce) {
    calledOnce = true;
    return;
  }

  alert("one done"); // or call custom call back here.
  alert("two done");
}
```

use doBoth for the onClick handler for the both button. This will start both animations almost at the same moment. they will both call the common handler, but only the last to finish will execute the important logic in the call back.